# Does the New Google Session Hijacking Technique Require Access to my Computer

Tags: google, oauth2

There is a new article explaining the details of the new Google OAuth2 exploit where a Google session can be restored using a Chrome token.  But what I can't seem to find on Google or in the article itself is...

Am I correct in understanding that a malicious actor would need either access to my computer and Chrome profile (local cookies) in order to implement this exploit?

https://www.cloudsek.com/blog/compromising-google-accounts-malwares-exploiting-undocumented-oauth2-functionality-for-session-hijacking

Comment: The article is about the analysis of malware. So, the malware runs on the victim. Is that what you are asking? Or are you asking about some other kind of access?

Comment: Okay, so in order for a malicious actor to be able to implement this attack, they need to already have access to or have compromised my computer?  I.e. they are not able to do this remotely by running a web site that I've signed in to?  Or by intercepting network traffic? I guess that answers my question then.